# Is there a word to refer to your brother/sister without referring gender?

Tags: word-request

Is there a word in *formal English language* to refer to your brother(s)/sister(s) without referring gender? To be more specific; assuming that I have 2 brothers and 1 sister, I would like to make a sentence of the form

> I have 3 ______.

rather than

> I have 2 brothers and 1 sister.

Is there a word to fill in the blank space in the first sentence?

**An additional remark:**

I would like to know if there is a word like **"*brister*"** (I made this up!) meaning *brother and/or sister.* Possible use example:

> **John**: Jack, how many bristers do you have?
>
> **Jack**: Three. Two brothers and one sister.

**Note (after reading the comments):**

A quick dictionary lookup reveals the word ***"sibling"***. But "sibling" makes an emphasis to the *biological relationship* between the children. That is , it emphasizes that the children have their biological father and/or mother in common. What I am asking is something different and nothing to do with biology. To make it clearer, you have probably never heard a person introducing his/her brothers/sisters by using a sentence like "These are my siblings".

Comment: Why did you decide to make up a word instead of look for a synonym for brother or sister in a thesaurus? The [first result is "sibling"](https://www.merriam-webster.com/thesaurus/brother) on Merriam-Webster.

Comment: *shaking head* Dude, did you bother looking this up? I'm saying this because *sibling* is a common word.

Comment: That's not wrong! But "sibling" makes an emphasis to the biological relationship between the children. That is , it emphasizes that the children have their biological father and/or mother in common. What I am asking is something different and nothing to do with biology. To make it clearer, have you ever heard a person introducing his/her brothers/sisters by using a sentence like "These are my siblings"? :)

Comment: @meyuksel Why do you think "sibling" implies a biological relationship but "brother" and "sister" do not?

Comment: @CloeenV Please read my reply to the user "JackO'Flaherty" below. Thanks!

Comment: You're drawing a distinction that does not exist. "Siblings" means "brothers and sisters". It does not imply a biological relationship. (For instance, the phrases "step sibling" and "adopted sibling" exist.)

Answer (score 5):

***Sibling***

> a brother or sister:
>
> - I have four *siblings*: three brothers and a sister. ([Cambridge](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/sibling))

The word ***brister*** does not exist. There is ***brethren***, but it has a restricted meaning:

> (used as a form of address to members of an organization or religious group) brothers ([Cambridge](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/brethren))

In some double communities it can be used regardless of gender.

Comment: That's not wrong, @fev! But "sibling" makes an emphasis to the biological relationship between the children. That is , it emphasizes that the children have their biological father and/or mother in common.

Comment: You did not specify that in your question, and you should not expect answerers to guess it.

Comment: You're right! I should probably edit my question.

Comment: Brother and sister also imply biological parents in common. If you are describing a more general category of relationship, what is the word for it in your native language?

Comment: @JackO'Flaherty In Turkish, we have the word "kardeş" to mean brother and/or sister without referring to gender. In fact, the use of this word is very common in Turkish daily life. For example, our President regularly uses it (in plural from) to address the Nation. But, it never means "my siblings". In religious context, all muslims are considered "kardeş" to each other event though they do not have  a mother or father in common. Anyone can use it to address anyone without referring to gender and without implying a biological relationship.

Comment: @meyuksel I don't think you will find a direct translation of that word in English. The closest I can think of is the phrase "brothers and sisters." In English, we sometimes refer to close friends or compatriots as brothers or sisters, but you are right that we don't usually use "sibling" in that context. If you are asking about familial relationships, biological or not, then siblings is commonly used.

Comment: Communists would address the people saying _**Comrades!**_ , but I doubt it would work for your situation...

Comment: Maybe "kinfolk" would fit. Or, "my fellow X", where X describes the commonality.

Comment: @JackO'Flaherty I think you are getting pretty close! Do they use "My fellows" in this sense? There is a certain affection in calling you fellow citizens "brothers" and "sisters", it's just a different culture..., doubt English can render that other than by "brothers and sisters". "My fellow contrymen" sounds colder...

Comment: @fev *My fellow Americans* is quite common. *My countrymen* would be used without the word *fellow*. I haven't heard *my fellows*.

Answer (score 0):

The word you are looking for is “sib,” which may imply biological relationship but is also used, especially in anthropology, to mean a member of one’s kindred.

Comment: ["sib" has a much stronger sense of "blood relation" than sibling does](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/sib). Unless you're talking to anthropologists, I'm fairly sure "sib" would be understood as an informal shortening of "sibling", and the question asks for formal English.